# how to create a strict array in ActionScript 3?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, amf, strict

all.I'm using AMF0 for communication ,and I want pass a strict array type , but all arrays I created by many methods are still ECMAArray.

How can I create a strict array ?

Comment: like these: var array:Array = new Array(1,2,3); or var array:Array = [1,2,3]; or var array:Array = new Array();array['a']=1;array['b']=2;

Comment: Do you mean you want an IntArray or a StringArray?

Comment: I'm not sure.The AMF0 has a data type named Strict Array (A strict Array contains only ordinal indices; however, in AMF 0 the indices can be dense or sparse. Undefined entries in the sparse regions between indices are serialized as undefined.)

Answer (score 3):

Use `Vector` class, available from Flash player 10. This is both "strict array", that is, its indexes are from 0 to length-1 continuous, and it's also typed, so you can make a `Vector.<int>` and there will only be ints.

Comment: I created a vector array like this:var v:Vector.<int> = new <int>[0,1,2,];   But the server treat it as a object.

Comment: Hmmm. Perhaps then you need to delve deeper into AMF0 byte-wise object representation. If that thing uses a custom array storage format, you should pass it a ByteArray then, specifically formed in a function according to researched format.

Comment: Ok,I'm also think I should study the AMF0 data type deeper.Thank you for your advice.